# UIImageView-TableViewCell Crash iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uitableview, lazy-loading

I am getting a crash while adding uiimageView in a containerView inside uitableView. I am performing lazy loading, the images loads successfully but when i scroll the table upwards, application crashes, Please guide me what i am doing wrong.

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Thanks

Comment: You need to post your code especially on how you add the image view into the table view.

Comment: if ([[profileImg_tmpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"userImage"] == nil) {//Launch thread to fetch image
   
docImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loding.png"];
[self startItemImageDownload:[profileImg_tmpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forIndex:indexPath.row];}
else{docImageView = [[[profileImg_tmpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"userImage"] copy];
                

            }
            
        }
                
        [containerView addSubview:docImageView]  Application crashed at here when i scroll tableView up

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere you're using UIImage where it should be UIImageView.

Comment: I have solved it by making docImageView.image = [[[profileImg_tmpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"userImage"] copy]; thanks